# How to expose minikube IP to the localhost

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, minikube

I am trying to deploy a simple `nginx` deployment for learning purposes and created the following resources. I am running this setup in `macos`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: nginx.jananath.site
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: nginx
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Everything works fine ONLY if I try `curl -kv http://nginx.jananath.site` inside the minikube docker container after accessing it through `minikube ssh`

But What I want to do is, without ssh-ing into the minikube container, I need to access the same application locally (in the host machine where the minikube is running)

I tried the following steps but it doesn't work.

Get the `minikube` IP:

```
minikube ip
```

map it to the hostname in the local machine (where the minikube is running) at `/etc/hosts`

```
<MINIKUBE-IP> nginx.jananath.site
```

But still doesn't work. Can someone help me on this?

Note: I don't want the service `nginx` to be a NodePort but a ClusterIP as mentioned in the above service yaml.

Thank you,
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you use the docker driver, start minikube with `--ports 80:80` it will map the localhost port to the minikube node.
If you use macos with hyperkit driver it is `--hyperkit-vsock-ports=`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the port forwarding?

kubectl port-forward service/nginx 8080:80
This will forward port 8080 on your local machine to port 80 of the nginx service.

You can access your application via http://localhost:8080.

Comment: I want to access the application through Ingress not through the service itself.